# How many quotas does the each Sheets API method use?

Tags: google-sheets-api, quota

How the quota count? I don't understand the rule that API quota count.
Why does the quota count not be equal every day with the same setting in my design?

Using the same times of API everyday but it doesn't have the same quota.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3X3Eb.jpg

Comment: Please try to ask a more specific question.  For example, you could post a representative sample of your code together with results in the API dashboard that you are confused about.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to method quota consumption, there's no mention of it. Your quota varies per day depending on how often you make a GET/POST/PUT request - in short, API calls.

I think these are the only info available with Sheets Quota [Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits):

This version of the Google Sheets API has a default limit of 40,000 queries per day. And this for read/write:

[image]